# RLE text compression in c

Tags: c, compression

i want to write a code which converts for example this text: "aaaaaaabbbb" into :"a7b4".
It should read from one file and write to another. Here is the wrong part of the code and i cannot make it work. Ty for help..

```
        fread(&fx,sizeof(fx),1, fin);      // read first character
        while(!feof(fin))
        {
            fread(&z, sizeof(z),1, fin);           //read next characters 

            if(z!=fx) { fputs(fx, fout);            
                        fputs(poc, fout);              
                        poc=1;                        // if its different count=1 
                        fx=z;               // and z is new character to compare to
                       }
            else poc++;


            }

            fputs(fx, fout);                
            fputs(poc, fout);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my code (not an optimal solution) to solve the problem with comments....Hope it helps for your own code and program !!

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* file is a pointer to the file input where to read the line  */
    /* fileto is a pointer to the file output where we will put */
    /* the compressed string */
    FILE* file, *fileto;
    file=fopen("path_to_input_file","r");
    fileto=fopen("path_to_output_file","w");
    /* check if the file is successfully opened */
    if (file!=NULL)
    {
        /* the str will contain the non compressed str ing  */
        char str[100];
        /* read the non compressed string from the file and put it */
        /* inside the variable str via the function fscanf */
        fscanf(file,"%[^\n]s",str);
        /* the variable i will serve for moving character by character */
        /* the variable nb is for counting the repeated char */
        int i=0,nb=1;
        for (i=1;i<strlen(str);i++)
        {
            /* initialization */
            nb=1;
            fprintf(fileto,"%c",str[i-1]);
            /* loop to check the repeated charac ters */
            while (i<strlen(str) && str[i]==str[i-1])
            {
                i++;
                nb++;
            }
            fprintf(fileto,"%d",nb);

        }
        /* handle the exception for the last character  */
        if(strlen(str)>=2 && str[strlen(str)-1]!=str[strlen(str)-2]) 
            fprintf(fileto,"%c%d",str[strlen(str)-1],1);
            /* handle the string when it is composed only by one  char */
        if(strlen(str)==1)
            fprintf(fileto,"%s%d\n",str,nb);



        fclose(fileto);
        fclose(file);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
fputs(poc, fout); 
      ^^^
```

`poc` is an integer type. The first argument to `fputs()` is a string type. You can't mix and match the two.

Consider instead using:

```
fprintf(fout, "%d", poc);
```

but keep in mind that the output may sometimes be ambiguous when the count is greater than 10. For instance, the output:

```
12345
```

may stand for either `1 x 2, 3 x 45` or `1 x 23, 4 x 5` (for instance).